# send parameters from php to c++

Tags: php, c++

I want to send some string parameter to a cpp.exe from PHP thanks to exec function. The aim of the exe is to compute a rank of documents according to a query.

Here is the code in php :

```
 $query = "is strong";
    $file = "vsm.exe $query";
    exec($file,$out);
    echo $out[0];`
```

I received this output for echo $out[0];

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\analysis.php on line 25

But, my vsm.exe only work (meaning I receive my ranks in the $out variable as a string which is okay) when the query is without space:

```
 $query = "is";
    $file = "vsm.exe $query";
    exec($file,$out);
    echo $out[0];
```

I followed that example which works with integer parameter (this is not what I want, I want to send sentences):

```
 $a = 2;
    $b = 5;
    exec("tryphp.exe $a $b",$c_output);
    echo $c_output[0];
    $c_array0 = explode(" ",$c_output[0]);
    echo "Output: " . ($c_array0[0] + 1); 
    echo "Output: " . ($c_output[0] + 1);
```

How could I send strings including spaces (could be long text) as parameters to c++?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I actually find something but still not enough good:

    `$query = "is strong";
    $file = 'vsm.exe "is strong"';
    exec($file,$out);
    echo $out[0];`

It returns me the rank I wanted. However, I look for a way to use $query as a parameter, not directly the string "is strong".